# Gerund phrase or participle phrase

Tags: gerunds, complements, participle-phrases

Q1 :
Nothing would prevent him speaking out against injustice.

I guess that "speaking out against injustice" is a gerund phrase as an object complement. Am right?

Q2:
Last night I saw him riding his bike on the street, when I was walking to home.

I guess that "riding his bike on the street" is a participle phrase as an adjective. Am I right?

Comment: I think "Prevent  sb **from**  sth" is more natural to me !

Comment: Thank u so much! But I'd known it. I just wondered what this verbal phrase can be at this situation. And that example sentence is form British English.

Comment: riding his bike on the street = while he was riding right?

Comment: Actually since gerund is most often used as a noun, shouldn't Q1 be "*Nothing would prevent **his** speaking out against injustice*"?  Otherwise, if "him" is an object for "prevent", then "speaking" is also an object, but it needs a preposition, as @Cardinal suggests.

Comment: @VictorBazarov Yes, Gerund is a noun and it take the roles of Nouns, however, your possessive form didn't come to my mind!

Comment: @Cardinal: I am not sure how to take your exclamation point :-)  I guess, I'd like to say, "And...?"

Comment: @VictorBazarov I am saying you are right, using "his" was very good , and sorry for my terrible English !

Comment: you haven't heard about object complement?

Comment: @BlodMary If you can relate, mmm, this answer might help you regarding your first sentence and what Victor already committed - http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/67917/3463

Comment: As for this particular question, whether it's gerund or participle, you can refer to this answer - http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/94887/3463

Answer (score 1):

> Last night I saw him riding his bike on the street, when I was walking to home.

You could just say *Last night I saw him* and that sentence would still make sense.  So *riding his bike on the street* is modifying *him*.  Since adjectives modify nouns (or verbals), that means it's a participle.

> Nothing would prevent him speaking out against injustice.

You can't say *Nothing would prevent him* without the sentence feeling unfinished (unless a previous context fills in the blank).  The sentence needs an object, and nouns answer for objects.  Caveat: [subject complements](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/subjectcomplement.htm) but the verb *prevent* doesn't work like that.

So *speaking out against injustice* functions independently - i.e. it doesn't grammatically modify anything, so it'd have to be a noun and thus a gerund.

Comment: You can't say when I was walking to home.  Omit "to" the word "home"is not followed by preposition "to".it is often used as an adverb.

Comment: @Lawrence Your first quoted sentence would have been better if you placed that *when-clause* at the beginning of the sentence. Another modification that would make it better is to drop *to* before *home*, but I don't think it's mandatory. Nor do I think using it the way you did would make the sentence incorrect. But the most common practice is to drop *to* in such cases.

Comment: Another thing is *riding his bike* is never an adjective. It modifies a noun, but that doesn't mean it has to be an adjective. In this sentence - *"Look at that man over there in red shirt, who is the retired army officer."* - the relative clause also modifies a noun, but we are not calling it an adjective.

Comment: Adjectives modify verbs - > this seems too strange, because I have never known such things; can you please cite some example sentences where an adjective does modify a verb?

Comment: I think I meant *verbals*.  Corrected.

Comment: @LawrenceC ah got it what you meant by "verbal". You meant sentences like this, right? But can you really put an adjective to your "riding" sentence?

Comment: @Man_From_India in fact we do refer to relative clauses as adjectives, specifically as adjective clauses: http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/adjectiveclause.htm

Answer (score 0):

The verb construction "to prevent sb from  sth/doing sth" is often shortened to
"to prevent sb doing sth". Here you have a gerund. After a preposition you always have a gerund.

In sentence 2 (I saw him riding his bike ...) riding is traditionally seen as a participle. But you could interpret it as a gerund as well (I saw him + he was in the act of riding his bike). In such cases you might call it gp (gerund or participle).

Comment: Not really. In the sentence "I saw him (riding his bike)", the part in the parenthesis does not act as a noun, so there's no gerund in there. It's a participle, because it acts as an adjective, describing the state of the object, "him", in which you sam him. If you want a gerund, here's an example of it:  "(Reading books) is my favourite activity."