# "no + gerund" or "not + gerund"

Tags: gerunds, participle-clauses, gerund-clauses

In order to compare them, I wrote below sentences:

> 1. Reading books is the solution not watching TV [a moral advice].
> 2. Reading books is the solution no watching TV [a moral advice].
> 3. I considered not going to that party.
> 4. I considered no going to that party

I know that ***no*** is used with noun phrases and we must use ***not*** in the other [situations](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/no-or-not). The question is that a ***gerund (phrase)*** acts as a noun (phrase), but I do not think the second and fourth sentences are correct. Perhaps, because my ears are more familiar with the **not+verb+ing** due to the fact that I see negative present progressive more often. I am not sure, would you help me

---

**Added Information:** In order to be more specific, I changed gerunds to gerund phrases and noun to noun phrase.

Comment: 1. Reading books is the solution **to** not watching TV.

Comment: 2 and 4 are incorrect. We just don't use *no* in this context.

Comment: @AlanCarmack So the generalization that I previously faced in grammar lessons seem to be wrong, "We use no before a noun phrase". Or considering a gerund as a noun phrase is a fatal error

Comment: In Modern English grammar verb + ing is categorized into three classes - **1.** *Gerundial noun* (you can use **no** with it),  **2.** *Gerund-Participle form of verb* **3.** *Participle adjectives*.

Comment: @Man_From_India so you reject AlanCarmack's comment ?

Comment: @Cardinal I didn't read his comments. Now reading them, I agree with what he already said. My comment above was in response to your comment about generalization.

Comment: @Man_From_India I think **you can use no with it** and **We just don't use no in this context** do not convey similar things

Comment: @Cardinal They are not same thing. But see I have written that line in a bracket after *Gerundial Noun* to mean that **no** can be used with only *Gerundial Nouns*. In traditional grammar you have gerund and participle, but in modern grammar you will get only *Gerund Participle*. I have mentioned verb + ing can be classified into three distinct classes. It will help avoiding ambiguity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the following:

> There was no scaling that steep cliff.
>
> Going around the mountain was the sane choice, not scaling that steep
>   cliff.

The first means that the cliff was *impossible* to scale. The second simply refers to the action of scaling as a non-choice, a thing that exists but which is rejected.

> There was no reasoning with them.

It was impossible to reason with them.

**no** + the **-ing** form denies the very existence of the -ing nominal.

It is used with existential statements.

**not** + the **-ing** form accepts the existence of the -ing nominal, but negates its *presence here* (in this context).

> He said he liked fishing, not hunting.
>
> He thought fishing was acceptable, but said there should be no hunting.

He did not see them off:

> His not seeing them off on their journey made them sad.

It was impossible to see them off:

> He was in another country on a business trip. There was no seeing them off.

Comment: That is why your examples revolves around "to be" and "there be". I mean you said we should use **no** to reject any possibility of **existence**. Thank you

Comment: *The lifeguard wanted (there to be) no running at the swim club pool.*  I will try to think of a sentence where **no + -ing** is not existential.

Comment: @TRomano and you could end up with the same thing Man_From_India's suggested: *gerundial nouns*. ;-)

Comment: It might be worth adding that *no* + gerund is also used to prohibit actions (I'm not sure if this counts as the imperative mood or not). E.g., "No Smoking"

Comment: @ToddWilcox Even that is existential, though. The fuller sentence is, "No smoking **is permitted**, given that passive verbs are really copulatives with the past participle.

Answer (score 5):

In modern English grammar, **verb + *ing*** is catogarized into three classes:

- Gerundial Noun
- Gerund-Participle
- Participle Adjective

So whether **no** or **not** will come immediately before a **verb + *ing*** will depend on which class the *ing* form of verb falls into. Let's make it more clear: *it's only before **Gerundial Noun** that **no** occurs.*

So it boils down to identifying the class of **verb + *ing***. If we know which class they are in, we can easily tell whether **no** or **not** will be correct before it.

> **1.** No *hunting* is allowed here. [*Gerundial Noun*]
>
> **2.** He is the host today, and he is *entertaining* his guests. [*Gerund-Participle form of verb*]
>
> **3.** He is good at *entertaining* the guests. [*Gerund-Participle form of verb*]
>
> **4.** It was an *entertaining* show. [*Participle Adjective*]
>
> **5.** The show is *entertaining*. [*Ambiguous*]

First we will see the difference between a *Gerundial Noun* and *Gerund-Participle form of verb*, later we will focus on the difference between *Gerund-Participle form of verb* and *Participle Adjectives*.

**Gerundial Noun** vs **Gerund Participle form of verb**:

Both *Gerundial Noun* and *Gerund-Participle* has the structure of verb + *ing*. Here's the difference -

- When *Gerund-Participle* is formed from transitive verb + *ing*, it normally takes a Noun Phrase (NP) object, but a *Gerundial Noun* formed from the same verb don't take NP complement.

> **Hunting** *the rhinos* is a crime. [*Hunting* is a *Gerund-Participle of verb*, it takes a NP - *the rhinos*]
>
> **Hunting** *of rhino* is not allowed here. [*Hunting* here is a *Gerundial Noun*, and hence it doesn't take a NP complement. It however takes a Prepositional Phrase (PP) as complement - *of rhino*]

- A *Gerund-Participle of verb* can take *predicative complement* but a *Gerundial Noun* can't.

> I am surprised at **being** *asked* about such thing.

Here **being** is not a *Gerundial Noun*, it's a *Gerund-Participle form of verb*, because it takes a predicative complement after it.

- Modifier - *Gerundial Nouns* can be modified by an adjective, but not by an adverb. On the other hand a *Gerund-Participle* is modified by an adverb.

> Ali was ordered to be hanged for *mercilessly* **killing** two innocent students. [*killing* here is a *Gerund-Participle of verb*, and it's modified by an adverb - *mercilessly*.]
>
> Ali was ordered to hanged for *merciless* **killing** of two innocent students. [*killing* here is a *Gerundial Noun* and it's being modified by an adjective - *merciless*.]

- Determiner - *The* and other comparable determinatives occur with *Gerundial Nouns*, but not with *Gerund-Participle of verb*.

> Students, concentrate on your lesson. *No* **talking** among yourselves. [Here **talking** is a *Gerundial Noun* and it takes a determinative - *no* - before it.]
>
> Everyone believes Messi's decision of retirement from International football is an impulsive one, and it resulted from *the* **shattering** of hopes. [*shattering* here is a *Gerundial Noun*, and determinative - *the* - can easily sit before it.]

- Plural inflection - *Gerundial Noun* can have plural inflection, but a *Gerund-Participle* can never have.

> The **killings** of birds ... [Here **killing** is a *Gerundial Noun*]
>
> *Killings the birds is not acceptable. [Here *killing* is a *Gerund-Participle of verb*, and hence no plural inflection is allowed.]

**Gerund-Participle form of verb** vs **Participle Adjective**:

- Normally *Gerund-Participle form of verb* can take NP complement, but *Participle Adjectives* don't.

> The whole experience was **frightening**. [Here *frightening* is a *Participle Adjective*.]
>
> **Reading** *only textbooks* wouldn't help. [Here *reading* is a *Gerun-Participle* of verb, and it takes a NP - *only textbooks* as a complement.]

- The word - *seem* - can take *Participle Adjective* after it.

> The show seemed *entertaining.* [Here *entertaining* is a *Participle Adjective*.]

- *Participle Adjective* can be modified by *very* and *too*.

> The show was *very* **entertaining**. [*Entertaining* here is a *Participle Adjective*.]

**Hybrid Construction -**

> Stop *constant* **mixing** *the conflicting ideas*.

What *mixing* is here? It takes a NP - *the conflicting ideas* - as complement. At the same time it's being modified by an adjective - *constant*. In one hand it's a *Gerund-Participle of verb*, but on the other hand it's a *Gerundial Noun*. This type of construction is called *Hybrid construction*. The sentence quoted above with *hybrid construction* is marginally accepted. But the sentence below is widely accepted one -

> There is *no* **denying** *the fact*.

This *denying* taking NP - *the fact*. In that respect it's a *Gerund-Participle form of verb*. On the other hand it takes a determiner *no* just like a *Gerundial Noun*. such use of *no* is normally restricted to existential constructions with *there*.

**Some sentences people here asked which they were not sure why *no* or *not* comes before verb + *ing* -**

> - I'm surprised at not **being** asked about it.

We have already seen that *Gerund-Participle form of verb* can take a *predicative complement*. Here *being* took a *predicative complement* - *asked about it*. Here *being* is a *Gerund-Participle form of verb* and hence *not* comes before it.

> - Now I understand that not **going** to the party was a big mistake.

Let's try to insert a *predicative complement* with *going* in that sentence. What about *poorly dressed*? So the sentence would look like this - *Now I understand that (not) **going* to the party *poorly-dressed* was a big mistake.* So here also *going* is a *Gerund-Participle form of verb* and hence *not* is correct.

> - His not **seeing** *them off* made them sad.

Here *seeing* take a NP - *them off*. There is no doubt but that **seeing** here is a *Gerund-Participle form of verb*. So *not* is correct.

> - The best thing about a holiday is not **working**.

Here **working** don't take any complement. But try inserting an adverb with it. *The best thing about holiday is **working** slowly*. As **working** is being modified by an adverb, it's an indication that **working** here is a *Gerund-Participle of verb*. So *not* is acceptable.

> - **Walking** but not **running** was done today.

I don't like to cite this example when explaining *verb + ing* and whether *no* or *not* would come before it. Because this sentence contains ellipsis. The full version of the sentence would be - ***Walking*** was done today, but **running** was not done. This sentence is similar to ***Bob*** came, but **Hary** did not come. => ***Bod*** came, but not **Hary**.

Comment: (+1) I learned other classification: gerund phrase, present participle, and adjective, I think you went farther. I mean you consider two different type of gerund phrases: gerundial noun and gerund participle. I have never seen such categorization so far. BTW, thank you for the answer

Comment: @Cardinal I have completed my answer. Please read it. If any confusion, reply me back.

Comment: I didn't read it yet. I just want to thank you for your contributions to this question. I really appreciate that. Now, I'm going to read the answer.

Comment: So, using your techniques, one can distinguish between the correct usage of **no** and **not**. Especially, using an adverb and NP complement. It was really helpful. But, as a learner I think I couldn't even use such complex sentences currently and I think the existential case is the most common case for me in which I would use  **no** +gerund. But, I think this answer can help many others (Or probably me in near future). Many Thanks

Comment: @Araucaria but most hybrid constructions are marginally accepted except the existential sentence with *there*.

Comment: Hmmm, good post. But "it's only before Gerundial Noun that no occurs" <--. But in our hybrid construction that you mention, it is not a gerundial noun! It's a verb. (I've plus 1ed you, but the real answer to the hybrid problem is that there is no good answer. No good [i.e. clear] analysis has ever been given!)

Comment: @Man_From_India Btw, your first hybrid example isn't grammatical old bean.

Comment: @Araucaria thank you for reading my answer with such patience. I really have problem coming up with a correct sentence with hybrid construction. If I can't find, I will copy the sentence from books :P

Answer (score 1):

Gerunds are nouns.  Participles are modifiers.  Both are th base verb + *ing*.

*No* modifies nouns (it's an adjective/determiner) and *not* modifies verbs or other participles (it's an adverb).

Modifiers can follow *to be* and a few other verbs because these are copular verbs.

> No walking was done today.
>
> I tried to find the girl not walking.
>
> I was not walking today.
>
> Not walking was done today (wrong).

It can be complicated.  But generally if the *-ing* word is not right in front of a verb, then it's probably a modifier.

> Not walking, but running was done today. (This is okay, *not walking* is a phrase that technically modifies the entire rest of the sentence I think.)
>
> Running, not walking, was done today. (*Not walking* qualifies *running*)
>
> No file cleaning but deleting was done today. (This works only because *deleting* is a type of *cleaning*.  *But deleting* is the modifier of the noun *cleaning.*)

Comment: So "Not/No walking your dog everyday is not a good thing" - "No" or "Not"?

Comment: @Man_From_India In that case, *not* is correct. Also, *everyday* and *every day* are two different things. In your example, *every day* is correct and *everyday* isn't.

Comment: @ToddWilcox thanks for correcting me. But this answer says "gerund is a noun and participles are modifier, and both are the base verb + ing". In the sentence I mentioned in my previous comment, "walking" is not a modifier. Then it has to be a gerund according to the logic of this answer and if that's true it's a noun and it naturally should take **no** before it in that sentence also. Isn't it?

Comment: The answer also mentions *"It can be complicated. But generally if the -ingword is not right in front of a verb, then it's probably a modifier."* So if it holds true in my sentence *"walking"* is a modifier? Then *"walking"* in this sentence also a modifier - *No walking of dog is allowed here*? If that *walking* is a modifier, it means it's a participle, if that holds true, how *no* comes before a participle? It should be **not**, right?

Comment: In "No file cleaning" you placed a noun between "no" and "gerund". This can be easily justified by the old rule of "no with noun phrases". I mean it is not problematic.

Comment: @Cardinal right, but what about the sentences I mentioned in my comments above under this answer?

Comment: @Man_From_India what is the problem. It is not in front of any verb so it is modifier. Consequently we should use ***not*** if we want to be loyak to this answer

Comment: @Man_from_India but, personaly, I think walking is a gerund not a present participe and (not) walking your dog .... is a gerund phtase

Comment: @Cardinal So doesn't it complicate the rule? And what about "No/not walking of the dog is allowed".

Comment: @Cardinal (not) walking your dog... is a gerund phrase, but still we have to use **not**? Why not **no**?

Comment: @Man_From_India I have no idea, that is why I asked this question

Comment: @Cardinal Yes that's the problem with this answer. Does this answer help you in any way?

Comment: @Man_From_India I don't know all the grammar rules behind it, if there even are any. I just know that the following are correct and you would never hear/read a native speaker choose otherwise: "**Not** walking your dog every day is not a good idea", and "**No** walking *of dogs* is allowed."

Comment: @ToddWilcox That's okay, but does it really help a learner whose native language is not English?

Comment: @Man_From_India I think Tromano's answer is completely acceptable, did you see that?

Comment: "Gerund are nouns" <---. Lawrence, that's not correct. Gerunds are gerund-participle forms of verbs that are fulfilling the same function as noun phrases often do. So they are verb forms that are busy being Subjects or Objects or Complements of prepositions. They are still verbs.

Comment: @Cardinal I don't think I have understood completely what he meant by those things he mentioned while distinguishing the difference of meaning between "not + v ing" and "no + v ing". It's up to you, if it makes sense to you. And of course if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's some serious confusion in your question and, accordingly, in some of the answers as well. And all the confusion lies in the fact that your logic is seriously misguided and flawed.

> The first "wrong" premise: "No" is used with noun phrases and we must use "not" in the other situations.
>
> The second "wrong" premise: A gerund acts as a noun.
>
> The "wrong" conclusion: Therefore, "no" should be used with a gerund.

In order to show that the first premise is wrong, here are counterexamples where "not" is used with a noun phrase, "no" non-noun phrases.

> (a) **Not** all usage notes in dictionaries are reliable.
>
> (b) The conclusion is **no** better than the premises.

And here is a counterexample to the second premise that a gerund acts as a noun.

> (c) **Reading books** is the solution, not **watching TV**.

Yes, that's your own example, except for the comma before "not." Here, 'reading' and 'watching' are both gerunds. Now, do they both act as a noun? If so, "reading books" and "watching TV" both must be compound nouns, as in "English books" and "LED TV". Unfortunately, though, neither "reading books" nor "watching TV" can be considered a compound noun in your example. So it's inherently wrong to say that a gerund acts as a noun.

I guess what you were trying to say was that a gerund phrase (such as "reading books" and "watching TV") acts as a noun phrase, which is entirely different from saying "a gerund acts as a noun."

Remember, if either of the two premises is wrong, you can never obtain the right logical conclusion. So, unless you can prove that both the two premises are right, your conclusion doesn't mean anything, leading only to more confusing answers.

Comment: @Cardinal You have not provided any reason why you think that "Not a, Not all, none, etc" are irrelevant. I suggest that there might be more to what you write off as irrelevant than meets the eye. Moreover, you haven't rebutted the fact that "no" can be used to negate not just noun phrases as shown in example (b).

Comment: It's not that you don't know the exact meanings of a gerund phrase, present participle, and what not. It's just that your oversimplification of the so-called "rule" is at the heart of your question, and that the illogicality arising from the oversimplification causes all the confusion both in your question and all the other answers.

Comment: And that's exactly why you won't be able to be satisfied with any of the answers as long as those answers are based on your false premises.

Comment: In fact one the answers completely satisfied me. btw, **not all (of)** is something different from **not**. **Thats** why I think it is irrelevant. In the case of b, I must work on it although it sounds odd to me. You can say something is not good or whatever or something is no longer better than ... . I'm working on it.

Comment: Also, I edited the question

Comment: It is cool bro, I am a leaner. There is no doubt that I make mistakes. But, I think most of persons specially who answered the question were able to understand my intention.

Comment: In fact, since these people who are natives among them didn't criticize the question. This made me think the question is OK. BTW, I, personally, eagerly want to be specific, especially in grammar issues. In general, I accept the deficiencies of the question. But, I get used to ask (rarely answer) such questions on ELL

Comment: @jk Do you know why **no** is not used in this sentence - *Not all usage notes in dictionaries are reliable.*? And why it's *not* there?

Comment: @jk why *no* here, but not *not* in here - *The conclusion is no better than the premises.*?

Comment: @jk As you have mentioned that other answers are wrong, what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: @jk this answer doesn't help OP, I guess. All it does is make him more confused. You haven't explained anything.

Comment: @Man_From_India How does it make the OP (more) confused when you point out the fundamental flaw in the question? Like I clearly laid out in my answer, the gist of the OP's question is based on some flawed premises. Maybe you might try to answer the question anyway, ignoring the flaws, but that's not exactly answering the question itself.

Comment: @Man_From_India Take your own answer, and I quote, "it's only before Gerundial Noun that no occurs." If so, in TRomano's example "There was no scaling that steep cliff," the "scaling" is a gerundial noun? Wait, what did you say about the gerundial noun? You said, "a Gerundial Noun formed from the same verb don't take NP complement." Now, the "scaling" does take an NP complement "that steep cliff", doesn't it? So, how it is that the OP can make any sense out of all this mess is just beyond me, to say the least.

Comment: @JK2 You forgot one important thing. OP is not a native speaker of English, he is learning a new language. He's trying to find some way to overcome some of his problems. Some of his concepts need to be modified, I know. But it's not his fault, many grammar text books contain such info. But that doesn't mean you will show him more of those example sentences which trouble already him without providing any way to solve his problem.

Comment: @JK2 Ah I got it. First my answer is not complete. Second that sentence is different. It's an existential sentence with *there* at the subject position. You would normally find *no* there.

Comment: @Man_From_India Sorry to say this, but it's not just incomplete but illogical, just as the OP's question is. As long as you ignore this apparent illogicality, all these rules after rules -- and even some more terms and more new rules -- won't get you and the OP anywhere. All you get is a longer list of exceptions to all those rules after rules. At some point, you'll have to admit that it just doesn't add up.

Comment: @JK2 you're somewhat right. But if that was the case, "grammar" wouldn't have come into existence in the first place.