# Dont stand close to the TV

Tags: grammar

He was standing near to the TV. (distance is short.)

"Step back. **Dont stand close to the TV.**"

Does it sound natural and grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't stand close to the TV** is a natural sentence. You can even say, **"Don't stand too close to the TV"** if the distance is really short. If a person is sitting close to the TV you can change **stand** to **sit**.

Answer (score 5):

> Step back. Dont stand close to the TV.

It's an imperative sentence. And this is a completely grammatical sentence.

The verb - *stand* - can license a Preposition Phrase (PP) as a complement, and that can express the location/position of the subject. Here the PP is *close to the TV*, and the head Preposition is *close*; within this PP structure the head preposition takes another PP - *to the TV* - as complement.

In the nested PP - *to the TV* - the head preposition is *to*, and it takes a Noun Phrase (NP) - *the TV* - as complement.

**N.B** - The *to* in the PP *close to something* is a Preposition, not the infinitive marker, and that's why it's incorrect to use the base form of verb after that *to*.

> They are very close *to* **winning** the game. [CORRECT]
>
> They are very close *to* **win** the game. [INCORRECT]

Comment: This all looks completely correct. You'd probably know better than me, but I can't help thinking at least *some* non-native speakers might need a bit more help with your final point. Specifically, *They are **winning** the game* involves a straightforward **BE + (continuous) verb participle**, but in *They are **close to** winning* it's a ***gerund*** (i.e. - it's acting as a ***noun***, not a verb, which is why it can be preceded by the preposition phrase *close **to***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm afraid to say that's not the case. Here *winning* in *close to winning the game* behaves the same way as the *winning* in *after wining the game*. This *winning* is not a noun, it is still the verb. One simple reason is a noun don't generally takes a NP as complement, but here *winning* takes a NP as a complement, much like a verb.

Comment: This involves fine distinctions between *when is an **-ing** form a verb, and when is it a gerund noun?*, which I'm not always clear on. I take your point that *winning **the game*** implies it's more "verby" than "nouny", but I think it's relevant to consider *They are close to **success*** (where we can substitute an alternative that's unquestionably a noun) and *Winning **is** important* (anything serving as the subject of a verb is probably best called a noun).

Comment: @FumbleFingers *winning* there at the start of a sentence is still a verb. Anything can be a subject, noun is not the only one. There is a distinction between word-form and lexeme. *Winning* is the word form of the lexeme - *win*. Generally it's lexeme that are grouped into word class (parts of speech).

Comment: @FumbleFingers once I wrote an answer regarding the distinction. It's here in this link: https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/94887/3463

Comment: It's when I get to things like your example *Hunting the rhinos is a crime = Gerund-Participle*, whereas *Hunting of rhino is not allowed here = Gerundial Noun* that my eyes just glaze over. I simply don't see how the presence or absence of ***the*** in the first version makes a blind bit of difference, nor do I see how this "syntax classification" could be affected by switching between *is a crime* and *is not allowed here*. When it gets to that level of fine distinctions, I think the categorisation system itself has outlived its usefulness.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why is such classification relevant only when it can be affected by switching between complements (*is a crime* / *is not allowed here*)? It's also not just the presence or absence of *the*, but it does make a difference, because how else would you justify saying "Sorry, you can't put *the* before *Hunting the rhinos*, but you can before *Hunting of rhino*."? Well, the only way would be by acknowledging that fine distinction!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I actually had the same exact question yesterday, as well. I found [this answer by snailplane](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/114533/3395) (the penultimate paragraph) very helpful as it neatly lists those differences. (: The meat of the post is this: "It is a mistake to say a gerund is a noun simply because the clause it appears in is functionally similar to a noun phrase." which, by the way, is why you can safely switch between those complements.

Comment: @userr2684291: I'm not sure whether you're asking me a question, or trying to teach me something. If the former, you'll have to hope Man_From_India can enlighten you. If the latter, I can only repeat in different words what I've already said: *I think it's **unhelpful** to apply  such fine dividing lines between categories, at this level*. Consider, for example, ***atom, crystal, prion, virus, bacteria, mammal*** with respect to the category ***alive***. The bottom line is that no "definition" adequately disambiguates all cases, even though the category is very useful *in general*.