# A gerund problem

Tags: gerunds

I am given two questions and I have to identify whether the gerund is used as subject, object, complement, or used after a preposition.

> 1. **Asking** questions is easier **than answering** them.
> 2. He preferred **playing** football **to studying** his lessons.

Answer is

In the first sentence the gerund **answering** is used as complement of the verb **is** and in the second sentence the gerund **studying** is used as object of the preposition **to**.

But what I think is the structure of both the sentences is the same and both of the gerunds are objects of preposition(excluding the gerund **asking**).

Am I right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where from did you get these info?

Comment: @Man_from. Wren and Martin

Comment: I can understand about the second sentence, because this is how you see it in a classical traditional grammar book. But what you said about the first sentence in your question is really dubious. I really wonder if the book really says it. Could you please recheck it once again please?

Comment: Piyush, Your first sentence is an example of Term Comparison. The comparative clause - *answering them* is a Gerund-Participial Clause and is associated with the second term. And this clause is the complement of the Preposition Phrase (PP) - *than answering them*, which (I mean the PP) is in tern governed by the Adjective - *better*. And the Adjective Phrase (AdjP) is *easier than answering them*. And so, on the sentence level it is Noun Phrase - *Asking questions* (Subject) + Copular Verb - *is* (Predicator) + AdjP - *easier than answering them* (Subject oriented Predicative Complement).

Comment: And one more point to add here. *Object* is a kind of complement and it is relevant/restricted within the territory of Verb Phrase, as far as I know. But I understand in traditional grammar it may be (mis)used the way you put it. In modern books you will never see it is written like the object of the preposition, rather you will see something like *complement of the preposition*.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are correct.

The gerund in the first sentence you posted is the object of the preposition "than". That prepositional phrase can be removed and the sentence would still be correct:

> Asking questions is easier.

You can do the exact same thing to the second sentence:

> He prefers playing football.

A gerund used as a complement is usually required for the sentence to make sense:

> Her intent is running for office.
>
> Her intent is for office. (This doesn't make sense)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sentences below:

> There is no point in **breaking** the seal. 
>   They were **entertaining** the troops.

In the sentences above, traditional grammar call *breaking* a Gerund and *entertaining* a Present Participle. 
Consider the Gerund - *breaking*. The verb lexeme is *break*, and the form of Gerund is *breaking*. 
Consider the Present Participle - *entertaining*. The verb lexeme is *entertain*, and the form of Present Participle is *entertaining*. 
Interesting both the Gerund and Present Participle has the same form. There is no verb lexeme that has different form for Gerund and Present Participle, And hence there is no ground for saying that Gerund and Present Participle have different inflectional form. 
Historically, the suffix *ing* is derived from traditional grammar's Gerund and Present Participle. The suffix *ing* that is derived from Gerund used to form noun from verb. Over the period it started to expand its territory and ended up licensing dependents that are not only associated with Nouns (*hunting* of rhinos) but that that are associated with Verbs too (*hunting* the rhinos). And it is this extension that gives rise to Nominal Gerund and Verbal Gerund. But the traditional definition of Gerund ('Verbal Noun') fails to recognise that it is actually a verb in case of Verbal Gerund. 
So in Modern Approach, we don't have Gerund and Present Participle as two separate category, rather we will group them under the term Gerund-Participial. However, we classify the verb+*ing* into three:

- Gerund-Participial form of verb (relevant to the question here)
- Gerundial Noun
- Participial Adjective

For reading further, please refer to my other [answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/94887/3463) on this topic.

---

> **Asking** questions is easier than **answering** them.

In the sentence above *asking* and *answering* is Gerund-Participial form of verb. The predicator (function) is realized by the verb - *is*, and it takes two complements - Subject (realized by a Gerund-Participial clause - *Asking questions*) and Subject Oriented Predicative Complement (realized by an Adjective Phrase - *easier than answering them*). 
Inside the Predicative Complement, the head adjective is *easier* and it licenses a complement realised by a Preposition Phrase (PP) - *than answering them*. Inside the PP, the head preposition is *than* and it takes a complement realized by a Gerund-Participial cause (*answering them*) which is formed from the Gerund-Participial form of verb - *answering*,

> He preferred **playing** football to **studying** his lessons.

*studying his lessons* is the complement of the preposition *to*. And *playing football* is the Object of the verb - *preferred*.

---

Object is a kind of complement and it is relevant/restricted within the territory of Verb Phrase, as far as I know. But I understand in traditional grammar it may be (mis)used the way you put it. In modern books you will never see it written like *the object of the preposition*, rather you will see something like *complement of the preposition*.